# How to resolve the error `Could not find "store" in the context`?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

```
[17:28:29] Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of
"Connect(AppNavigator)". Either wrap the root component in a`<Provider>`
or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding
React context consumer to Connect(AppNavigator) in connect options.

This error is located at:


in Connect(AppNavigator) (at App.js:17)


in RCTView (at View.js:44)


in ActionSheet (at ActionSheetProvider.js:56)


in ActionSheetProvider (at App.js:16)


in ApolloProvider (at App.js:15)



in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)



in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)


in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)


in RCTView (at View.js:44)


in RCTView (at View.js:44)


in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

Comment: Some code would be nice so we can see where things may be going wrong?